# Multiple admins in Firebase - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm trying to create a client-side only application using Firebase as a database service and I'm experiencing some difficulties defining a security rules that will allow multiple `'admin'` users access to some data.

My data schema looks like this:

```
{
  admins: {
    simpleLogin:1 : true,
    facebook:1234 : true
  },
  myData: {
    simpleLogin:1 : {
      .....
    },
    google:1234 : {
      .....
    },
    facebook:1234 : {
      .....
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to allow a logged in user to write to its place inside 'data' object (I'm writing with `ref.child('myData').child(auth.uid).set(...)` and **to prevent a user to access other users data**. In addition, a user that its `uid` is defined in `'admins'` data should be able to read/ write to all `'myData'` object.

My security JSON is defined like this:

```
{
 "rules": {    
   "admins": {      
     ".write": false,
     ".read": true
   },
   "myData": {      
      "$user_id": {
         ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid ||  
              root.child('admins').hasChild(auth.uid)",
         ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid || 
              root.child('admins').hasChild(auth.uid)"
       }
   }
 }
```

- I'm adding users to `'admins'` manually using a local node service that I'm running each time I would like to make a user an admin.

Of course this is not working, since `'myData'` has no explicit definition of read/write permissions - so when I'm trying to read `ref.child('myData').once('value', function() {..})` with a user that its `uid` is in `'admins'` - I'm not able to do so.

I'm trying to run the following query and gets with a user that its uid is in `'admins` and gets `permission denied`

```
ref.child('myData').once('value', function(snapshot)     
  {console.log(snapshot.val())}, function() {console.log(arguments)}))
```

Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Do your admins need to access `myData` or is it sufficient that they access `myData/$user_id`?

Comment: Answer below. But if that doesn't answer it, **edit** your question to add the code for the query that you're trying to run.

Comment: Hi, It didn't help :( I'm trying to run the following query: ref.child('myData').once('value', function(snapshot) {console.log(snapshot.val())}, function() {console.log(arguments)})) with a user that its uid is in the admins list - and get 'permission denied'

Comment: by the way, I can't grant '.read': true permissions to myData node and leave the write restriction to each sub uid - which will allow everyone to read but to modify only their nodes - but I don't think it is a good pattern...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you from adding rules directly to `myData`. This gives admins direct access to `myData` (and all nodes within it). If the user isn't an admin, they can only access their own node.

```
"myData": {
   ".read": "root.child('admins').hasChild(auth.uid)",
   ".write": "root.child('admins').hasChild(auth.uid)",
   "$user_id": {
      ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid",
      ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
    }
}
```

Regarding Firebase's [cascading security rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-cascade): The key part to understand is

> The child rules can only **grant** additional privileges to what
>   parent nodes have already declared.

Basically, if you're an admin, then you're granted read and write at the myData level (and it's children) and nothing can revoke that. If you're not an admin, you could still gain access at a lower level, as in the above example.

Comment: Hi Anid! That works, however - I cannot understand why. Can you please explain? according to the documentation (https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-cascade) if I restrict read permissions to 'myData' to admins only - how can non-admins can read inner nodes? isn't it the same as the example from the cascade example? what am I missing?

Comment: Glad to help. I edited the answer with a brief explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Every user should be able to read the `admins` node.

```
"rules": {    
   "admins": {      
     ".write": false,
     ".read": true
   },
```

In case you are worried: there is no risk in allowing everyone **read** access to this node.